# Difference between http:client and Requests

Tags: python, api, postman

In Postman, while I want to change my code from 'curl" to "python", there are two options, one is called "http.client(python3)", and the other one is called requests. 
I'm trying to write a script to call Restful api in python, and i use pycharm to try both of the options. The first one doesn't work and the second one works, and i can successfully get access_token.
Could someone explain whats the difference between the two, and I'm new to python btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http.client is the python 3 standard library (batteries included) way to make rest calls

Requests is a popular third party library (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) that is commonly used to make calls.  You'll need to install it in order to use it (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/)

Comment: Highly recommend the requests library. It's the most downloaded python library for a reason..  makes REST calls and handling the response super easy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I installed pip and request library even though Im not sure what pip is. However, I'm curious why when i used the template of 'http.client' in postman, it does not work, however it works when i used requests template.